# Split continuous counter by time period

Tags: graphite

I have a series list `*.in.count` that represents number of messages going into a queue. If I plot the list as-is it will be a perpetually going up line:

[image]

What I want to know is how many messages go into a queue aggregated and summed by hour, and reset by day. Something like this:

[image]

I experimented with Graphite functions but couldn't find a way to achieve this.

Comment: I think it's unlikely that you will be able to achieve this with Graphite alone. You'll need another component in front of Graphite to reset the metrics daily.

Answer (score 4):

To aggregate events over time in Graphite you can combine the usage of `group()`, `sumSeries()`, and `summarize()`.  The *group* function pulls metrics into a single series, then *sumSeries* adds them up, then *summarize* aggregates them for an interval.

For example:

1 hour sums:

```
summarize(sumSeries(group(*.in.count)),"1h")
```

or

1 day sums

```
summarize(sumSeries(group(*.in.count)),"1d")
```

Then, to get the graph to look like you want (i.e. like a bar chart), you should set the "Line Mode" to **Staircase Line** and "Area Mode" to **Stacked** or **All**.

Comment: `summarize` approach didn't work for me. Test metrics were reported both by dropwizard's(codehale) `counter.inc` and `meter.mark`. With both metrics it was perpetually going up line till app restart. And summarize gave same (constantly increasing) graph either with or without grouping and sumSeries.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but for the sake of other searchers:

**To sum up or calculate count(total) per interval:**

```
hitcount(perSecond(your.count), '1day')
```

Afaik it does all the black magic inside. Including but not limited to `summarize(scaleToSeconds(nonNegativeDerivative(your.count),1), '1day')`
and also there should be scaling according to carbon's retention periods (one or many) that fall into chosen aggregation interval.